# TextView selectable just on long click

Tags: android, textview

I have many `TextView`s and `ImageView`s interleaved and I want to select one word of a `TextView` with a long click. If I set all the `TextView`s as selectable with `mTextView.setTextIsSelectable(true)` the scroll doesn't work well and when I click over one of them, the view scrolls to set it as first element.

I thought that I could do something like:

```
mTextView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                mTextView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

But I have to perform the long click two times, one to set it as selectable and the second to select the word. And then I have to override something like `onScroll` or `onClick` to set the `TextView` as not selectable again.

Someone knows some solution?

Edit: I need to select words of the `TextView`s but I just want to perform the long click over that `TextView`s. They are created in runtime and added to a `FrameLayout`. Maybe I't could be possible perform all gestures on the `FrameLayout` minus the `onLongPress`...

Comment: You set the mTextView.setTextIsSelectable(true); inside your OnlongClickListener for that view. I would put right after the findViewById and before the onClickListener. or maybe I missed the question.

Comment: Thank you @RogerBelk for your answer, but I don't know how that could help me. I don't want the textviews selectables all time because the scroll behavior is not correct when I set this way, so I just want to make it selectable on long click to perform some actions with the word selected.