# Android - Click through a TextView when not long-pressing (selecting) the TextView

Tags: java, android

What I'm trying to achieve is have a TextView inside of a CardView (that's in a RecyclerView) be selectable only when you long-press the TextView. And if you don't long-press the TextView, it is ignored and the input (click) is passed on to the parent (CardView) which has it's own event to do when pressed.

I've tried one solution where I add a "OnLongClickListener" to the TextView and enable "selectable" when triggered. However when you short-press the TextView, it blocks the input from reaching the parent CardView, which prevents the CardView from performing it's action, which is expanding the CardView.

```
textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I'm trying to find a solution to have the TextView be essentially ignored and pass the input to it's parent when it isn't long-pressed. Anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

I've looked here already: [TextView selectable just on long click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42598797/textview-selectable-just-on-long-click)

Comment: i think  you can add a on click listener to your textview and in that listener just perform the card views action ... as it happens when other place is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Just write  `textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);`

Remove onLongClick event, When you long press on Textview then it auto select textview text

Comment: Setting the TextView to selectable will also result in the TextView blocking the CardView from being clicked when you do a short-press.

Comment: set clickable and focusable  false for cardview

Comment: But the CardView needs to be clickable. It has a click event...

Comment: add android:focusable="true" for Textview